# Windows to Ubuntu transition

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows

My question is somewhat different from the traditional ones.
I expect to receive a desktop that has preinstalled Windows but I am not interested even in booting them, so the question is:
Do I have to do anything before plugging a usb stick with Ubuntu? Do I have to, at least once, boot in Windows and then install Ubuntu? Or could I from the first boot of the desktop, just boot the usb stick and install Ubuntu?

Comment: Often best to have backup of Windows. You may later find one game or application that only runs in Windows or later sell system and then it needs Windows. One user posted that he buys system with HDD and removes it and adds SSD. Then later sells it with HDD and unused Windows.

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to boot to windows. If you already have a Ubuntu CD/DVD or USB then you just need to boot to that and install Ubuntu (you can then choose to format the HDD/SDD etc.)

By default the PC may offer the choice of booting from your Ubuntu USB, but if not you may need to go into the system bios to set boot order and/or allow booting from your Ubuntu USB device.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it last year with 18.04 (think the same apply to 20.04)...Just boot directly in ubuntu and choose the options. No need for pre boot win, you can leave it as dual boot, or as ubuntu install it will erase the disc and be the only OS on the HD. Have fun.